# How do you extract an embedded attribute value from a previous attribute value in an XPath query?

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy, scraper

I'm trying to "select" the link from the onclick attribute in the following portion of html

```
<span onclick="Javascript:document.quickFindForm.action='/blah_blah'" 
 class="specialLinkType"><img src="blah"></span>
```

but can't get any further than the following XPath

```
//span[@class="specialLinkType"]/@onclick
```

which only returns

```
Javascript:document.quickFindForm.action
```

Any ideas on how to pick out that link inside of the `quickFindForm.action` with an XPath?

Comment: which xpath engine do you use ? which language ?

Comment: I'm working with the Python library Scrapy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the XPath in a Java application and it worked ok:

```java
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.StringReader;

    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
    import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
    import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

    public class Teste {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            Document doc = stringToDom("<span onclick=\"Javascript:document.quickFindForm.action='/blah_blah'\" class=\"specialLinkType\"><img src=\"blah\"/></span>");
            XPath newXPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            XPathExpression xpathExpr = newXPath.compile("//span[@class=\"specialLinkType\"]/@onclick");
            String result = xpathExpr.evaluate(doc);
            System.out.println(result);

        }

        public static Document stringToDom(String xmlSource) throws SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            return builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlSource)));
        }
    }
```

Result:

```
Javascript:document.quickFindForm.action='/blah_blah'
```

Comment: That worked. Don't know what I was doing wrong; perhaps I had set up the page incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

If Scrapy supports XPath string functions this will work

```
substring-before(
   substring-after(
      //span[@class="specialLinkType"]/@onclick,"quickFindForm.action='")
   ,"'")
```

It looks like it also supports regex. Something like this should work

```
.select('//span[@class="specialLinkType"]/@onclick').re(r'quickFindForm.action=\'(.*?)\'')
```

Caveat: I can't test the second solution and you will have to check that `\'` is the proper escape sequence for single quotes in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I used xquery but it should be the same in xpath. I used an xpath function "tokenize" that splits a string based on a regular expression (http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_tokenize.html). 
In this case I split the string basing on " ' "

```
        xquery version "1.0";
        let $x := //span[@class="specialLinkType"]/@onclick
        let $c := fn:tokenize( $x, '''' )
        return $c[2]
```

That in xpath shoud be:

```
        fn:tokenize(//span[@class="specialLinkType"]/@onclick, '''' )[2]
```